# Wildcard subdomains redirected to www with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

There seem to be a million posts on StackOverflow on this topic, but none seem to be exactly what I'm after.

Basically, I'm trying to redirect all random non-existent subdomains to the "www" version of a URL.

For example, if someone types "whatever.mydomain.com" in the address bar, this should redirect to "www.mydomain.com". This is also a WordPress driven site, so I'm wondering if WP's existing rewrite rules are causing the redirect loops that have happened with many of the pieces of code I've tried.

It should also be noted that currently the site redirects from the non-www version to the www version, but I can't for the life of me find where that is occurring. It's not in the .htaccess file, and I don't know where else to look for that.

Thanks.

Comment: is this post help? http://forums.serverbeach.com/showthread.php?7034-Fake-Non-Existing-Subdomain-redirection

Comment: First, you need to have a wildcard domain entry in your DNS records. Then you add that as an alias to your main domain. As for the existing www redirect, have you checked the VirtualHost for the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this at the top of your .htaccess file in the root folder of `mydomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#for all requests on mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#if they are not for the www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#301 redirect to www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That causes a redirect loop. I'm thinking I might have a DNS setting that's conflicting.

Comment: I had a typo: redirect was going to `mydomain.com` instead of `www.mydomain.com`, which would cause the loop. Fixed above

Comment: I spoke to my host and a helpful tech wrote the rewrite rul for me. I don't have enough rep points to answer my own question so soon, but when I do I'll post it, probably sometime tomorrow.

Comment: Also, I tested your solution above and it does indeed work. I'll post the other one later on. Thanks again.